# MongoDB - Index creation on array

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I want to create an index for an array of objects. In the following structure, I want to create index for digitalId

```
"equi": [{
"id": 10001,
"digitalId" : [
    {
        "namespace": "designId",
        "value" : "uuid"
    },
    {
       "namespace": "operateId",
        "value" : "0x876231"
    }
]]
```

What's the correct syntax to create index programmatically?

```
collection.createIndex(Document.parse("{\"equi.digitalId.nameSpace\": 1}"),
            new IndexOptions().name("Collection name"))
```

(or)

```
collection.createIndex(Document.parse("{\"equi.digitalId\": 1}"),
            new IndexOptions().name("Collection name"))
```

Comment: See [Multikey Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)

Comment: I applied like collection.createIndex(Document.parse("{"equi.digitalId": 1}"), new IndexOptions().name("Collection name")). When I do some search on digitalId array like {"equi" : { "$elemMatch" : { "digitalId" : { "$elemMatch" : { "nameSpace" :  "operateId" , "value" : "0x876231" } }}}.explain() gives something like " winningPlan: 
       stage: 'COLLSCAN' " in the result. So , this means the index is not applied to array field?

Comment: In general, `'COLLSCAN'` means that index is not applied on a target query (either an index doesn't exist  _or_ the query is not able to use an existing index).

Comment: Try `collection.createIndex({ "equi.digitalId.nameSpace": 1})` - parse is useless.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried & Prasad. I am having another question on index . In the above example, instead of array of objects (digitalId) , i want to save as key , value pair for the values. "digitalId" : { "designId": "uuid",
        "operateId" : "0x876231"
    }
Basically , the domain class in Java looks like Map<enum, String>. In this case , how can i apply the index for digitalId?